# Fetch API request receives 401 unauthorized access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am trying to access an API however I was receiving an error code 401. I tried my endpoint on POSTMAN and it's working just fine.

I was able to provide a bearer token on POSTMAN.

if appropriate here is the code.

```
async function fetchData(){
const response = await fetch('http://192.168.3.143:4040/mmi-endpoints/v0/article/custom_query', {
  method : "POST",
  mode: "cors",
  cache: "no-cache",
  credentials: "include",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
  }
})
const data = await response.json()
setData(data)
}
```

Comment: You are apparently unauthorised. We don't have a reference for the API you are using, so we don't know how you should authentication yourself. And its certainly nothing to do with SQL Server.

Comment: You can also add a bearer token to a fetch call via the [Authorization Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)

Answer (score 1):

You could add the Bearer token to the headers of the request.

```
const token = 'your-t0ken_xyz'

async function fetchData() {
const response = await fetch('http://192.168.3.143:4040/mmi-endpoints/v0/article/custom_query', {
  method : "POST",
  mode: "cors",
  cache: "no-cache",
  credentials: "include",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type" : "application/json",
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
  }
})
const data = await response.json()
setData(data)
}
```

Comment: I tried your code above, however, on the console, it says CORS policy blocked the request. I tried to disable CORS through the chrome extension.